# What is the purpose of a Manager Class?

Tags: oop, actionscript-3, naming-conventions

I see a lot of classes labelled "Manager". How is a manager class used?

For example, does it get used by composition like this?:

```
var m: Mananger = new ManagerClass();
m.doSomething();
```

Comment: I do believe it manages things

Comment: @M28: not if the code has been obfuscated.

Comment: Could be anything I guess...However I've seen some projects where the "Manager"-suffix is used for classes in the business layer, for example "OrderManager", "CustomerManager" etc.

Comment: Okay, duh, just rewrote my question...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Classes like that are used to manage a set of objects of another class, which are often resources.

For example, let's say you have a pool of database connections, each one represented by an object of `DBConnection` class.

If your code needs to connect to DB via a pool of connections, it will merely ask `DBConnection_Manager` class for a new connection. Why do we need the manager class?

The Manager class will consult its list of DBConnection objects, and determine if any of them is un-allocated, and return one. If all are allocated, it will either create one and add to the pool (subject to max connections allowed limit) or place the request on queue, or report back failure.

ALL of this functionality is full hidden from the caller - the nitty-gritty details of managing the pool are the job of the Manager class.

This is just a specific example, but the idea is that resource management is centralized and encapsulated withing a Manager class and the user code merely asks for "a resource".

I'm not sure if there's a bona-fide "design pattern" for this approach, though I found at least one web page that says so: http://www.eventhelix.com/realtimemantra/ManagerDesignPattern.htm

---

Update: in case of actionscript, such a class could be used to manage sounds, or event listeners, or GUI widgets (e.g. context menus)

Answer (score 16):

Manager classes are the common dumping ground for code that somehow didn't fit somewhere else. They also tend to be or become [god classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object).

Answer (score 6):

[Some](http://blog.codinghorror.com/i-shall-call-it-somethingmanager) consider managers to be a [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)

Comment: I just was going to ask such a question and this answer beats my expectations. BTW: 'some' is really cool guy.

Comment: Uncle Bob does, too. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/17100/clarify-the-single-responsibility-principle

Answer (score 3):

it usually means somebody is implementing a design pattern and doesnt know (or doesnt want to use) the formal name for it.  you'll have to read the code to draw any meaningful conclusions.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, manager class should be used in these conditions:

1. Multiple objects need to be process
2. Pass object list to caller is not enough, you should provide some advance functions such as select the `max` or the `min` one
3. The objects to be managed should belong to one class (manage easily)